# Why is the breakpoint of PyCharm suddenly greyed out when I debug the program?

Tags: python, pycharm

Breakpoint changes its color and the program does not stop there anymore, when I debug it.
This is how it looks before I run:

[image: An image of the breakpoint before debug]

and the breakpoint changes its color once I start to debug the program:

[image: An image of the breakpoint once the debug button has been hit]

How could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason (probably by mistake) you must have [muted the breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html#debugtoolbar). When you mute the breakpoints, they stay regular, and **only when you start running** (debugging...) - they change to grey which indicates they are muted.

The icon to mute/unmute is on the Debug Toolbar, with a line over a breakpoint icon:

[image: An image of the debug toolbar, focused on the left pane, highlighting the "mute breakpoints" button (a breakpoint symbol (red dot) with a grey line crossing it diagonally)]

You can notice that the icon itself has kind of a grey background which indicates that it is selected and (all) breakpoints are muted. You want it to be **without** the grey background which means it is not selected and all breakpoints are active

Comment: Did not know I can mute all breakpoint at once. Thought, I could do it only one-by-one. Nice feature, but very hard to recognize (if activated).